# tflearn softmax output does not sum up to 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, softmax, tflearn

I am working on regression for multi-categorical value using 2-layer GRUs.
Thus, I used the activation function for the last layer as “softmax” whose output needs to be summed up to 1.
However, as I tested using the testing set, the output of the prediction value was not added to 1 (for each time step). I checked the “categorical_crossentropy”  in "objective.py" of tflearn but it seems the definition is correct (y_pred uses the predicted value).

Here is my tflearn code. Am I doing something wrong?

```
Train_Label = np.zeros((num_Train, max_time, 3))

for i in range(num_Train):
    Train_Label[i,:, :] = tflearn.data_utils.to_categorical(tmp[i, :, 0], 3)

tf.reset_default_graph()

net = tflearn.input_data([None, max_time, num_Feature])    
net = tflearn.gru(net, num_Feature, activation='relu', inner_activation='sigmoid', return_seq=True, dynamic=True, weights_init='truncated_normal')
net = tf.stack(net, axis=1)
net = tflearn.gru(net, 3, activation='softmax', inner_activation='sigmoid', return_seq=True, dynamic=True, weights_init='truncated_normal')
output = tf.stack(net, axis=1) #output of encoder (stacked in terms of time axis)

net = tflearn.regression(output, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=0.0001, loss='categorical_crossentropy')
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_verbose=0)
model.fit(Train_Feature, Train_Label, n_epoch = 10, show_metric=False, batch_size=10, shuffle=False)

tmp_score= np.array(model.predict(Test_Feature))
```

Comment: To what value does it add to? It could just be rounding and FP errors.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro It was different which time instance I look at ranging from 0.5 to 1

I should have added a softmax layer not just changing the activation function of the last GRU layer. So the modified code is as follows and the results correctly sum up to 1 for each time steps.

    net = tflearn.gru(net, num_Feature, activation='relu',

    inner_activation='sigmoid', return_seq=True, dynamic=True, weights_init='truncated_normal')

    net = tf.stack(net, axis=1)

    net = tflearn.time_distributed(net, tflearn.fully_connected, [num_classes])

    output = tflearn.softmax(net)